# yii user management non editable profile fields

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

can we specify profile fields that cannot be modified by the user?

The idea is to let the user modify only a limited set of the profile fields.

Comment: Modified means ?? clarify your question please

Comment: rather than specifying 'readonly'=>true for every field, if I can configure the default profile update page to allow only a selected fields to be displayed and updateable.  I hope I am clear.

Comment: If you don't want them to be displayed then remove them if you don't want them to be editable then set them as read-only. What else do you need?

Comment: the default modification procedure in the update view is to render the _form.php which loops over  all the profile_fields for update.  Hence if we can indicate in some fashion that a particular field is not updateable and then use that indication in _form.php to eliminate the fields that cannot be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a `CActiveForm` you can define a field as readonly like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField("username", $model->username, array('readonly'=>true)); ?>
```

Comment: Pls see the comment above in response to Ninad's comment.  Thanks